# how do I set opacity in css

Tags: html, css, vue.js

I have this css and it works fine on localhost but when I host is online it changes to 1%
this is my css

```
.myOverlay {
   background-color: #08101d;
   opacity: 90%;
}
```

when i host the project online it changes to this

```
.myOverlay[data-v-1c81d41d] {
    background-color: #08101d;
    opacity: 1%;
}
```

I tried using 0.9, but that also changes to 1%

Comment: And if you set it with `opacity: 0.9;` instead of `opacity: 90%;`. Does it change something ?

Comment: that also did not work, I don't know if there is any global css the is overriding my css

Answer (score 2):

Use like this

```
.myOverlay {
   background-color: #08101d;
   opacity: 0.9;
}
```

another

```
.myOverlay[data-v-1c81d41d] {
    background-color: #08101d;
    opacity: 1;
}
```

> 0 to 1 (eg- 0.5)